# Stop attempt to reconnect after first 'max' attempt

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I tried to configure Spring Rabbit Application through `application.properties` and `JavaConfig` with the below code. While the application works when RabbitMQ is running. I want to ensure that after the first `AmqpConnectException` I want to ensure there are no more retries.

Although trying different ways of configuring like setting up `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` with

```
BackOff recoveryBackOff = new FixedBackOff(5000, 1);
```

or by configuring beans like `RabbitTemplate`, `SimpleRetryPolicy`, `ExceptionHandler`, `ConnectionListener`, `AmqpChannelFactoryBean` etc following many answers by Gary and others here, I was still not successful and need help. I am not sure if my configuration is incomplete or if I am unable to interface Spring Framework itself at the required point where it retries. Added code and exception log and pom.xml below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestRabbitApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestRabbitApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
class rabbitConfig {
    @Bean("cachingConnectionFactory")
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cFactory.setHost("localhost");
        cFactory.setPort(5672);
        cFactory.setUsername("guest");
        cFactory.setPassword("guest");
        cFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
        cFactory.setConnectionTimeout(10);
        return cFactory;
    }
}

@Service
class myStreamer {

    @Bean
    public Supplier<String> streamer() {
        return () -> "Hello...";
    }
}
```

LOG

```
[2m2022-06-22 22:49:40.419[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7244[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
[2m2022-06-22 22:49:40.436[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7244[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Channel 'application.streamer-out-0' has 1 subscriber(s).
[2m2022-06-22 22:49:40.441[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7244[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m started bean 'streamer-out-0_spca'
[2m2022-06-22 22:49:40.454[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7244[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.TestRabbitApplication  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started TestRabbitApplication in 3.399 seconds (JVM running for 4.385)
[2m2022-06-22 22:49:40.469[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7244[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mo.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
[2m2022-06-22 22:49:40.475[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7244[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[   scheduling-1][0;39m [36mo.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@5c457394]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[8], headers={contentType=application/json, id=cccf75a1-e6cb-f3e8-405d-56dc315accee, timestamp=1655918380459}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:475)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:461)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2173)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2146)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.doRabbitSend(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:250)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.send(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint.handleRequestMessage(AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:180)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1223)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1342)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectHostPort(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:653)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:618)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565)
    ... 52 more
```

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-rabbit</name>
    <description>Demo Spring Examples</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=false
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.enabled=false
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.enabled=false
```

etc

While testing for connection in ApplicationRunner may solve in some way, I want to see if this can be solved with config properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think that there is a reconnect.
What you have so far is this:

```
@Bean
public Supplier<String> streamer() {
    return () -> "Hello...";
}
```

Which in Spring Cloud Stream is wrapped into a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` with 1 second polling interval. So, what you see in your logs are independent messages produced by the poller and failed because of that connection exception.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources.

You may consider to have an error handler which would stop your binding from producing data on that poller interval:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programmatic_way

Comment: Thank you for immediate help, I understand the issue now. Will try the links you shared soon and accept the answer.

Comment: Tried the sample suggested in the above link and was able to programatically close the Binder. However I had to use `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` to hook into. I will try using ErrorChannels soon. How do we do transaction management like JTA in Stream based Messaging as the Flux emit has no idea if the Runnable passed to the Spring Integration succeeded or not as each polled emit  `Flux.just("Helloo...").doFinally(c->{System.out.println(c.describeConstable().get().constantName());})`  has signal `ON_COMPLETE` although the end result is `AmqpConnectionException` since the broker is down anyway

Comment: This sounds like a separate SO question with much more info.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the listener; you are using a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` to send messages, it looks like you are using spring-cloud-stream with a `Supplier<?>` function.

You need to stop the binding.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programmatic_way

Autowire the `BindingsLifecycleController` and stop the binding.

Comment: You can only accept one answer, Artem's is more complete, so accept that one (when you are ready).